# Fetch Dropdown Selected Value on "list.phtml"

Tags: magento-1.9, dropdown-attribute

I am created one custom dropdown attribute , now i want to fetch dropdown selected value display in "list.phtml".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//just put this code after product name 

<?php

$attrvalue=$_product->getIdols();//get your attribute for particular product

$productModel = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
$attr = $productModel->getResource()->getAttribute("idols");

if ($attr->usesSource()) {
$idols_label = $attr->getSource()->getOptionText($attrvalue);
}
?>
<div class="idols">
<?php echo $idols_label;?> 
</div>
```

Comment: Giving this error using above answer Fatal error: Call to a member function usesSource()

Comment: put this code into your foreach and just echo $idols_label where you want this code is tested and working

Comment: can you explain how to put foreach in your code

Comment: first you have to get value of your attribute in variable $attrvalue

Comment: <?php $attrvalue=$_product->getIdols();?>  and make sure your attribute "Allow HTML Tags on Frontend" should be yes

Comment: "Used in Product Listing" should be yes not "Allow HTML Tags on Frontend" sorry...

Comment: now can you upvote my question and i am upvote your answer @pawan kumar parmar